# Has a smart contract ever been enforced by a court?

Tags: contract-law, breach-of-contract, digital-contract

Is there any precedent for a so-called "smart contract" ever being enforced in a court of law anywhere in the world?

###### Edit

As per @David Siegel, this is not a duplicate with [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77482/how-does-contract-law-apply-to-smart-contracts):

> The linked question is not at alla duplicate. No valid answer to it could be a full answer to this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does contract law apply to smart contracts?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77482/how-does-contract-law-apply-to-smart-contracts)

Comment: The linked question is not at alla duplicate. No valid answer to it could be a full answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

In *Rensel v. Centra Tech, Inc.*, No. 17-24500-CIV-KING/SIMONTON, 2018 U.S. Dist. LEXIS 100720 (S.D. Fla. June 14, 2018), the plaintiff brought class-action securities claims against the developers of a cryptocurrency app. The defendant sought to force the plaintiff into arbitration instead of litigation, but the court held that the smart contract through which the plaintiff had purchased the defendant's cryptocurrency did not require arbitration.